# R install Vennerable package on windows

Tags: r, installation, package

I am not able to install the Vennerable R package from https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/vennerable/ on my Windows 7 with newest R (2.13.0).

I tried following:

1. installed from RGui and selecting R-Forge repos:
   there was no Vennerable package in the list
2. installed from RGui using "install package from local zip file":

   ```
   can not open compressed file 'Vennerable.tar.gz/DESCRIPTION'
   ```
3. converted tar.gz into zip and installed from RGui using "install package from local zip file":

   ```
   can not open compressed file 'Vennerable.tar.gz/DESCRIPTION'
   ```
4. tried manual install: `install.packages("D:/Downloads/Vennerable.tar.gz", repos = NULL)`

   ```
   can not open compressed file 'Vennerable.tar.gz/DESCRIPTION'
   Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
   ```

Note: there is a file DESCRIPTION.

What should I do to install this package?

---

Links on [package page](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=474) are dead (to either [Windows build](http://r-forge.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/latest/Vennerable_2.0.zip) and [package source](http://r-forge.r-project.org/src/contrib/Vennerable_2.0.tar.gz)).

Comment: @Marek if I use install.packages this shows up: ""package ‘Vennerable’ is not available (for R version 2.13.0)""

Comment: I tried -- LINK DOES NOT WORK!!! https://r-forge.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/latest/Vennerable_2.0.zip

Comment: The link to the Vennerable Windows binary file is DOWN

https://r-forge.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/latest/Vennerable_2.0.zip

does anyone have a mirror?

thanks

Comment: OK. My bad I don't check links. I edit your question a little.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the project admin person listed on the r-forge page?

Comment: I was able to compile it for R-2.13. You could checked if it works: http://www.filedropper.com/vennerable201.

Comment: [There is a chance it will be available again](http://r-forge.r-project.org/forum/message.php?msg_id=4470&group_id=474)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can checkout the source: open the terminal and run the following command

```
svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/vennerable
```

Then build without vignettes.

```
cd  vennerable/pkg
R CMD build Vennerable/ --no-build-vignettes
```

and finally to install it:

```
R CMD INSTALL Vennerable_3.0.tar.gz
```

(Your build might be in a different name than Vennerable_3.0.tar.gz).

For me it generated the following error:

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘graph’, ‘RBGL’, ‘xtable’ are not available for package ‘Vennerable’
```

Then I had to go to R, run the following command:

```
install.packages(c("graph", "RBGL", "xtable"))
```

and then go back to the terminal and run the `R CMD INSTALL ...` command again.

Comment: Due to changes in `switch` (R-2.13) package no longer compiles. On other hand correction is simple.

Answer (score 3):

[Vennerable package has been updated](http://r-forge.r-project.org/forum/message.php?msg_id=4509&group_id=474) and now version 2.1 is available from R-forge using

```
install.packages("Vennerable", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Comment: Did not work for me, for anyone else failing when trying this:
https://github.com/frankkramer/rBiopaxParser/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Stenemo Works for me. There is no dependencies (from bioconductor) but it works. "package ‘Vennerable’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and figured it out. The issue was with how the package is archived. There is a directory called 'Vennerable' within the top level directory which is called "Vennerable_2.2'. I unzipped the archive. Then I navigated to the 'Vennerable' subdirectory, and zipped that. Then I ran the installation using the new 'Vennerable.zip' archive. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a tar.gz archive, you likely have the package's *source* files.  You must build it first before installing the package. See [section 1.3 of the Writing R Extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Checking-and-building-packages)

See also your [other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009222/r-venn-diagram-package-venerable-unavailable-alternative-package), where I provided this link to the built package for R 2.13.0 x86_64:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/jthetzel-public/Vennerable_1.1.1.1.zip

Comment: I change link in your answer from pdf version to html one.

Comment: @Marek Thanks for the edit, Marek.