# Rectangular Venn diagram

Tags: r, venn-diagram

Is there a way to plot in R the following Venn diagram as squares rather then circles?

```
venn.plot <- draw.triple.venn(1883,598,2151,218,221,611,95, c("AL", "RL", "R"),scale=TRUE)
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a great ready made solution available, see:
1) http://stackoverflow.com/q/6009222/1317221
2) http://stackoverflow.com/q/1428946/1317221

Answer (score 4):

`draw.triple.venn` does return "...an object of class gList containing the grid objects that make up the diagram. Also displays the diagram in a graphical device unless speciﬁed with ind = FALSE. Grid::grid.draw can be used to draw the gList object in a graphical device." (from the VennDiagram help file), so with some creative editing of the components of that object you might be able to draw squares instead of circles.

(note: please delete the anonymous edit I accidentally wrote up)
Here's the way to do it.  Don't tell my boss I wasted time digging up this hack.

```
Rgames> hack.plot[[6]]$x<-unit(c(.25,.75,.75,.25),unit='npc')
Rgames> hack.plot[[6]]$y <-unit(c(.25,.25,.75,.75),unit='npc')
```

To get the square properly placed, those coordinates should have been `range(as.numeric(hack.plot[[6]]$x))` and so on.  I believe the three circles are in slots 6,7, and 8.